# Need help Inner join and where condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, jupyter-notebook

I don't know why below codes did not work.

Problem: Using `INNER JOIN`, find the minimum “Average Student Attendance” for a community is where hardship is 96

```
SELECT b.Community_Area_Name, min(b.Average_Student_Attendance) FROM CENSUS_DATA as a 
INNER JOIN CHICAGO_PUBLIC_SCHOOLS as b
ON a.Community_Area_Number =b.Community_Area_Number
WHERE a.hardship_index=96
GROUP BY b.Community_Area_Name
```

Error in jupyter notebook:

> File "", line 2 INNER JOIN CHICAGO_PUBLIC_SCHOOLS as b ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Error in SQL server:

> "A.COMMUNITY_AREA_NUMBER" is not valid in the context where it is used.. SQLCODE=-206, SQLSTATE=42703, DRIVER=4.22.36

Comment: what's the tables' structure..? what is the specific issue?

Comment: What is the actual error/issue that you see. We don't know how it is not working otherwise.

Comment: Hi there, the problem I would like to solve is using INNER JOIN to find the minimum “Average Student Attendance” for a community is where hardship is 96. I use Jupyter notebook to run the code but below error showed:    File "<ipython-input-45-a2b5bec90f88>", line 2
    INNER JOIN CHICAGO_PUBLIC_SCHOOLS as b
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Yes, I understand the problem you are trying to solve. But, I don't know what specific issue your current query is giving. That is what we would need to know.

Comment: as Guy L already said, you should post an example of `CENSUS_DATA` and `CHICAGO_PUBLIC_SCHOOLS`, please.

Comment: Hi this is the data of 02 table: 
Chicago Socioeconomic Indicators: https://ibm.box.com/shared/static/05c3415cbfbtfnr2fx4atenb2sd361ze.csv
Chicago Public Schools: https://ibm.box.com/shared/static/0g7kbanvn5l2gt2qu38ukooatnjqyuys.csv

Comment: Does it produce any error when you execute it in sql server?

Comment: It was showed this when I tried to run on SQL server - "A.COMMUNITY_AREA_NUMBER" is not valid in the context where it is used.. SQLCODE=-206, SQLSTATE=42703, DRIVER=4.22.36
Learn more about this error

Comment: Can you check your column names in both the tables? Should that be Community_Area_Number or Community Area Number as there is no underscore in your csv files?

Comment: It's Community_Area_Number. I also tried to include "Community_Area_Number" but it did not work

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I managed to it. The problem was described in article "work with real data set" week 4. We need use double quotes in our queries. Something like this

```
SELECT MIN("Average_Student_Attendance")
```

Answer (score 0):

Doublequotes will solve your problem, but what i found is when i doublequote Hardship_Index, i got error. But below code works on Jupyter.

```
%sql select min(PS."Average_Student_Attendance"), CD.Hardship_Index  from CENSUS_DATA as CD INNER JOIN CHICAGO_PUBLIC_SCHOOLS as PS ON CD."Community_Area_Number" =PS."Community_Area_Number" WHERE CD.Hardship_Index = 96 GROUP BY CD.Hardship_Index
```

Answer (score -1):

Lists in SQL are is in ascending order by default so you do not need to use the minimum function to solve this query. I was able to solve this problem with the following WHERE statement.

```
WHERE C."HARDSHIP_INDEX"=96 ORDER BY S."Average_Student_Attendance" LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: This solution is way off.  OP wants grouping by `Community_Area_Name`.

Comment: It worked for me, the problem statement does not explicitly say group by has to be used.

Comment: "find the minimum 'Average Student Attendance' for a community".  For a community is where `GROUP BY` comes into play.