# Newbie SQL Learner (Inner Join)

Tags: sql

Problem: Find the minimum “Average Student Attendance” for community are where hardship is 96. Hint: use INNER JOIN

I have two sets of data, one named CENSUS_DATA (which has the HARDSHIP_INDEX) and the other named CHICAGO_PUBLIC_SCHOOLS which has the (Average_Student_Attendance). They both share the COMMUNITY_AREA_NAME column.

This is what I tried:

```
select C.HARDSHIP_INDEX,CH.AVERAGE_STUDENT_ATTENDANCE
from CENSUS_DATA as C
INNER JOIN CHICAGO_PUBLIC_SCHOOLS as CH on C.COMMUNITY_AREA_NAME = CH.COMMUNITY_AREA_NAME
where C.HARDSHIP_INDEX = 96
```

I keep getting a syntax error right on the first "C." and I don't know how to change this.

I also am not sure if I wrote the whole thing correct either...just trying to start somewhere. Thank you!

///////////Update:

[image: Space added and min()]

Still an error

Comment: What does the syntax error say?  Depending on the parser, the lack of a space between the comma and CH.AVERAGE_STUDENT_ATTENDANCE might be problematic.

Comment: Maybe related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52520752/need-help-inner-join-and-where-condition Apparently a classmate of yours had similar problems.

Comment: What's the exact error message?

Comment: Have you tried putting a space in like @Leonard suggested?  What is the result?

Comment: updated  your question  .. add  your exact error message, your tables schema  a proper data sample and the expetced  result

Comment: I tried the space, and still received an error. I posted a screenshot in the actual question

Comment: What program / app are you running the query in? And how?

Comment: Maybe there is a BOM (Byte Order Mark) at the start of the file, just before the`SELECT` ? This often confuses parsers.

Comment: Since we don't know what parser you're using, we'll have to guess what syntax it likes. Does this work: `select C.HARDSHIP_INDEX from CENSUS_DATA as C`? how about this: `select HARDSHIP_INDEX from CENSUS_DATA` how about this: `select HARDSHIP_INDEX from CENSUS_DATA as c`? You can solve your own problem if you just try some tests and do break the problem down.

Comment: Since the error message marks the "C" character, maybe that's a reserved one. Try methods indicated on last comment, or change your alias to another one (for example, CE). Also try to execute your query directly on SQL console. When you have a functional query at console, you can try to do it on python.

Comment: Like @Phil asked, Are you running Python as the app?  Are you using SqlLite?  Or SqlServer? Or which sql??

Answer (score 0):

I just finished this class and after a lot of similar errors I found that the problem is from the keys. You need to make sure your primary key references the foreign key.

```
SELECT S."Community_Area_Name", S."Average_Student_Attendance", C."HARDSHIP_INDEX"\
FROM SCHOOLS as S INNER JOIN CENSUS as C ON \
S."Community_Area_Number" = C."Community_Area_Number" WHERE C."HARDSHIP_INDEX"=96
```